# XML Schema that describes a self-describing XML document

Tags: xsd

Is it possible to write an XML Schema that describes an XML document that lists a set of elements and then *requires* other elements on that same XML document to use those values as either attributes and/or sub-elements?

Example: define a list of locations, then force location attributes and/or location elements to be of those values.

```
<root>
  <locations>
    <location>Home</location>
    <location>Office</location>
    <location>School</location>
  </locations>
  <addresses>
    <address location="Home">...</address>
    <address location="Office">...</address>
  </addresses>
</root>
```

or

```
<root>
  <locations>
    <location>Home</location>
    <location>Office</location>
    <location>School</location>
  </locations>
  <addresses>
    <address>
      <location>Home</location>
      ...
    </address>
    <address>
      <location>Office</location>
      ...
    </address>
  </addresses>
</root>
```

I am failing hard at finding the proper way to search for this information. I suspect it is either not possible or I just don't know the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Schema in its current version 1.0 cannot help you here. You cannot model any dependencies between nodes and their values ("if node X has a value of ABC, then there must be a "ABC" node somewhere else in the XML document"), I'm afraid.

There are other XML validation mechanisms, such as [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com) or [Relax NG](http://www.relaxng.org/) which sometimes can do things XML Schema can't do. You might want to check out those and see if you can achieve your goal using such a tool.